# Stuck on weak convergence proof of a bilinear mapping.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

I'm trying to prove the following theorem from Ciarlet's Linear and Non Linear Functional analysis but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. Sorry if this trivial stuff. If anyone could give me some advice that would be great. Many thanks.

Let $B\in\mathcal{L}_2(X\times Y,\mathbb{K})$. Then 
\begin{equation} x_n \rightharpoonup x\;\text{in}\;X\;\;\text{and}\;\;y_n\rightarrow y\;\text{in}\;Y\;\;\text{implies}\;\;B(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow B(x,y)\;\text{in}\;\mathbb{K} \end{equation}
Where $\mathcal{L}_2(X\times Y,\mathbb{K})$ represents the space of all continuous linear functionals from the normed space $X\times Y$ into the field $\mathbb{K}$. We also use the following notation; $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ denotes weak convergence and $x_n\rightarrow x$ denotes strong convergence.

My attempt:

We are given the hint to write $B(x_n,y_n)-B(x,y)$ as $B(x_n,y_n-y)+B(x_n-x,y)$
\begin{align} |B(x_n,y_n)-B(x,y)|&=|B(x_n,y_n-y)-B(x_n-x,y)|\\&\leq |B(x_n,y_n-y)|+|B(x_n-x,y)| \\ &\leq \|B\|\|x_n\|\|y_n-y\|+|B(x_n-x,y)|\end{align}
Since $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ we know that $\|x_n\|$ is bounded and since $y_n\rightarrow y$ we can make the left hand side of the final inequality as small as we like. For the right hand side I'm slightly stuck. Since $B$ is continuous for fixed $y$ we can treat the mapping $x\in X \rightarrow B(x,y)\in \mathbb{K}$ as a continuous linear functional on $X$. Then I want to use the definition of weak convergence $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ for each $f\in X'$ to make the right hand side as small as I want. Does this seem correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this seems correct.